# How to define a list in struct in asp c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, struct

How can i define a List as field of struct?

Something like this :

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public decimal SomeDecimalValue;
    public int SomeIntValue;
    public List<string> SomeStringList = new List<string> // <<I Mean this one?
}
```

And then use that string Like this :

```
Private void UseMyStruct()
{
     MyStruct S= new MyStruct();
     s.Add("first string");
     s.Add("second string");
}
```

I've tried a few things but they all return errors and don't work.

Comment: Why dont you use `class` instead of `struct`?

Comment: You can always use `s.SomeStringList.Add()`;

Comment: ok i can,but i cant define List in Struct..
This is my problem..not using s.Add()..
Please read the post carefully.
And try this code if you are sure

Comment: @sine and @SWeko: How exactly will that work when the string list cannot be initialized? It can't.. it will throw a `NullRef`. The OP would have to initialize the list after instantiating the struct.

Comment: You´re absolutely right, overlooked that o_O shame on me...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot have field initializers in a struct.

The reason is that a field initializer is really compiled into the parameterless constructor, but you cannot have a parameterless constructor in a struct.

The reason you cannot have a parameterless constructor, is that the default construction of a struct is to erase its memory with zero bytes.

However, what you can do is this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    private List<string> someStringList;

    public List<string> SomeStringList
    {
         get
         {
             if (this.someStringList == null)
             {
                 this.someStringList = new List<string>();
             }

             return this.someStringList;
         }
    }
}
```

Note: this is not threadsafe, though it can be modified to be if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Public fields in structs are evil, and will stab you in the back when you are not looking!

That said, you can initialize it in the (parameterfull) constructor, like this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public decimal SomeDecimalValue;
    public int SomeIntValue;
    public List<string> SomeStringList;

    public MyStruct(decimal myDecimal, int myInt)
    {
      SomeDecimalValue = myDecimal;
      SomeIntValue = myInt;
      SomeStringList = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(string value)
    {
      if (SomeStringList == null)
        SomeStringList = new List<string>();
      SomeStringList.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Note that the `SomeStringList` will still be null if someone uses the default constructor:

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct(1, 2);
s.SomeStringList.Add("first string");
s.Add("second string");

MyStruct s1 = new MyStruct(); //SomeStringList is null
//s1.SomeStringList.Add("first string"); //blows up
s1.Add("second string");
```